# Cannot concatenate DB::table Laravel 5.7

Tags: database, laravel

I have an error in try concatenate in a query in my controller:

```
    $asignaciones = DB::table('asignaciones')
        ->join('dueños','asignaciones.dueno_id','=','dueños.id')
        ->join('choferes','asignaciones.chofer_id','=','choferes.id')
        ->select('asignaciones.*', 'dueños.nombre as dueño_nombre',
        'dueños.apellido as dueño_apellido','dueños.ci as dueño_ci','dueños.celular as dueño_celular',
        'choferes.nombre '+'choferes.apellido as chofer_fullName',
        'choferes.ci as chofer_ci','choferes.celular as chofer_celular')
        ->get();
```

The error message is:

> "A non-numeric value encountered"

My questions is, how  can I concatenate or unite two columns in one

in the line, `choferes.nombre '+' choferes.apellido` as `chofer_fullName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DB::raw()` like this:

```
$asignaciones = DB::table('asignaciones')
    ->join('dueños','asignaciones.dueno_id','=','dueños.id')
    ->join('choferes','asignaciones.chofer_id','=','choferes.id')
    ->select('asignaciones.*', 'dueños.nombre as dueño_nombre',
    'dueños.apellido as dueño_apellido','dueños.ci as dueño_ci',
    'dueños.celular as dueño_celular',
    DB::raw('CONCAT(choferes.nombre, choferes.apellido) AS chofer_fullName'),
    'choferes.ci as chofer_ci','choferes.celular as chofer_celular')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, i can see before